# How to find the minimum of $x^4+y^4+x^3+y^3+x^2+y^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

What is the minimum of $$x^4+y^4+x^3+y^3+x^2+y^2$$ subject to $x^3+y^3\leq -2$ ?

I tried to use $x^4+y^4=(x^2+y^2)^2-2x^2y^2$ and $x^3+y^3=(x+y)(x^2+y^2-xy)$ but I couldn't come to any conclusion. Any ideas ?

Please note, I need highschool based approaches.   But if not possible any approach is welcome.

Comment: are real numbers?

Comment: Yes in real numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$x^4+y^4+x^3+y^3+x^2+y^2$

$=x^2(x+1)^2+y^2(y+1)^2-(x^3+y^3)$

$\geq -(x^3+y^3)$

$\geq 2$

Equality holds iff $x=y=-1.$